# Find the shortest path sum in a matrix. Is Dijkstra not optimal for this case?

Tags: algorithm, go

I am trying to solve [the following problem from project euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=83) (please take a look at description and the example in the link, but here is the short explanation).

> in the matrix, find the  minimal path sum from the top left to the bottom right, by moving left, right, up, and down

Right after I looked at the problem, the obvious solution which came to mind is to create a graph from the matrix and then use [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path.

To construct a graph from a `N*M` matrix, for every `(i, j)` element I create a vertex `i * N + j` and connect it to any other vertex (to which it is possible to connect with UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT) and the edge will be the value of the element I am connecting to in the matrix. After that I create 2 other vertices `-1` connected to vertex `0` and `-2` connected to `N*M - 1` which will be my start and end vertices (both connection have 0 cost).

After this I am doing Dijkstra to find shortest path cost from `-1` to `-2`. My Dijkstra implementation uses priority queue and looks this way:

```
func dijkstraCost(graph map[int]map[int]int, start, end int) int{
    if start == end{
        return 0
    }
    frontier := make(PriorityQueue, 1)
    frontier[0] = &Item{value: start, priority: 0, index: 0}
    visited := map[int]bool{}
    heap.Init(&frontier)

    for frontier.Len() > 0 {
        element := heap.Pop(&frontier).(*Item)
        vertex, cost := element.value, element.priority
        visited[vertex] = true
        neighbors := graph[vertex]
        for vertex_new, cost_new := range(neighbors){
            if !visited[vertex_new]{
                if vertex_new == end{
                    return cost + cost_new
                }
                heap.Push(&frontier, &Item{
                    value: vertex_new,
                    priority: cost + cost_new,
                })
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

where Priority Queue implementation is taken from heap container (example PriorityQueue) with one minor modification:

```
func (pq PriorityQueue) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return pq[i].priority > pq[j].priority // changed to <
}
```

The graph that I am providing to the function looks like:

```
map[13:map[8:965 18:121 12:746 14:111] 16:map[11:803 21:732 15:537 17:497] 3:map[8:965 2:234 4:18] 4:map[9:150 3:103] 22:map[17:497 21:732 23:37] -1:map[0:131] 17:map[16:699 18:121 12:746 22:524] 1:map[6:96 0:131 2:234] 9:map[4:18 14:111 8:965] 11:map[6:96 16:699 10:630 12:746] 19:map[14:111 24:331 18:121] 24:map[23:37 -2:0 19:956] 2:map[3:103 7:342 1:673] 15:map[10:630 20:805 16:699] 18:map[13:422 23:37 17:497 19:956] 10:map[5:201 15:537 11:803] 14:map[19:956 13:422 9:150] 0:map[5:201 1:673] 6:map[5:201 7:342 1:673 11:803] 8:map[9:150 3:103 13:422 7:342] -2:map[] 12:map[7:342 17:497 11:803 13:422] 20:map[15:537 21:732] 21:map[16:699 20:805 22:524] 5:map[0:131 10:630 6:96] 23:map[18:121 22:524 24:331] 7:map[2:234 12:746 6:96 8:965]]
```

---

This works correctly but the problem is that it is considered inefficient (judging by [Hackerrank version of the problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler083)). It should run find the value of the best solution for `700x700` matrix in less than 4 seconds, whereas my solution takes 10 seconds.

I thought that I am doing something wrong in go, so I reimplemented the same solution in python (where it took approximately 70 seconds for 700x700 matrix)

---

**My question is:** Am I using the right approach to find the best solution in a matrix. If so what am I doing wrong with my implementation?

P.S. I have full go and python solution, just thought that even without them the question is too long.

Comment: Isn't this better asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @Tichodroma I am not sure the problem is with a code (I am not asking people to review my code), may be I am just using the wrong algorithm. Also the problem with code review is that there is not a lot of people there and it is hard to find people knowledgable in go there.

Comment: The code looks too examplish to be re-viewable, which would make it off-topic for CodeReview. Questions about which algorithm to use should not be posted there.

Comment: As each value in the matrix can go up to 10^9, your solution can encounter a number overflow problem, which can effect the running time.

Comment: @PhamTrung on my 64 bit machine int can hold the values int64 can hold and I can not see an overflow because 1000^2 * 10^9 can still hold in int64. I also tried the solution with int64 just in case (with no success).

Comment: A* would be faster than Dijkstra's if you have an admissible heuristic - can you think of one in this case?

Comment: Look like your implementation has problem, I just made a submission using Java, and it got accepted on Hackerrank.

Comment: Try the Go profiler. It draws you a nice picture with boxes sized according to time usage.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis ah, I forgot that A* is optimal with admissible and consistent heuristics. And the heuristics here is closeness to the final square (which can be calculated as taxicab distance. Thanks

Comment: @SalvadorDali Taxicab distance doesn't look like an admissible heuristic here. I can't see anything preventing a 0 or negative element in the matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dijkstra should pass, I just make a submission using JAVA, and it took less than a second to complete each task.

As I have mentioned, each value in the matrix can go up to 10^9, your solution can encounter a number overflow problem, which can effect the running time.

My code:

```
<!-- language:java -->

static int[]X = {0,1,0,-1};
static int[]Y = {1,0,-1,0};
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(
    // "output.txt")));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    Scanner in = new Scanner();        
    int n = in.nextInt();
    long[][]map = new long[n][n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            map[i][j] = in.nextLong();
        }
    }
    PriorityQueue<Pos> q= new PriorityQueue();
    long[][]dist = new long[n][n];
    for(long[]a : dist){
        Arrays.fill(a,Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    q.add(new Pos(0,0,map[0][0]));
    dist[0][0] = map[0][0];
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        Pos p = q.poll();
        if(dist[p.x][p.y] == p.cost){
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                int x = p.x + X[i];
                int y = p.y + Y[i];
                if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < n && y < n && dist[x][y] > dist[p.x][p.y] + map[x][y] ){
                    dist[x][y] = dist[p.x][p.y] + map[x][y];
                    q.add(new Pos(x,y,dist[x][y]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    out.println(dist[n - 1][n - 1]);
    out.close();
}

static class Pos implements Comparable<Pos>{
    int x, y;
    long cost;
    public Pos(int x, int y, long cost) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pos o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Long.compare(cost, o.cost );
    }
}
```

**Update**:

I think your Dijkstra implementation is not correct:

```
for frontier.Len() > 0 {
    element := heap.Pop(&frontier).(*Item)
    vertex, cost := element.value, element.priority
    //You didn't check for visited vertex here!
    visited[vertex] = true
    neighbors := graph[vertex]
    for vertex_new, cost_new := range(neighbors){
        if !visited[vertex_new]{//You can add same vertex multiple times here!
            if vertex_new == end{
                return cost + cost_new
            }
            heap.Push(&frontier, &Item{
                value: vertex_new,
                priority: cost + cost_new,
            })
        }
    }
}
```

In your implementation, you only update `visited` when the vertex pop out of the heap, thus, one vertex can be added and processed multiple time, so, it will significantly increase your time complexity.

To fix

```
for frontier.Len() > 0 {
    element := heap.Pop(&frontier).(*Item)
    vertex, cost := element.value, element.priority
    if !visited[vertex]{
        visited[vertex] = true
        neighbors := graph[vertex]
        for vertex_new, cost_new := range(neighbors){
            if !visited[vertex_new]{
                if vertex_new == end{
                   return cost + cost_new
                }
                heap.Push(&frontier, &Item{
                   value: vertex_new,
                   priority: cost + cost_new,
                })
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: thanks for telling me this. Now the question is with what I am doing wrong. I highly doubt it has something to do with overflow (my test on 700x700 matrix with values from 1 to 100 takes approximately 10 seconds). Ps, I can not see your solution (HR is hiding it) but it is not important as long as I know that it passes all tests within 1 second.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I think there is a fault in your implementation, look at my update :)

Comment: you are totally correct. Thank you and it was so sad to see that I made such a mistake. Would you mind telling me how much time it took you to pass tests 5 and 6?

Comment: @SalvadorDali it was 0.86s for test 5 and 0.85s for test 6